# Vuex: binding dynamically to a property of the state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm interested in making a custom checkbox component that will contain a number of divs and some content.

I have a store that looks like this:

```
var store = Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    lights: true,
    sound: false
  }
});
```

Is there any way that I can create a custom component that could accept one of these properties (`lights` or `sound`) and manipulate them?

I have everything in a real muddle right now. I have created a template:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <my-switch :name="'lights'"></my-switch>
    <my-switch :name="'sound'"></my-switch>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next up I was using [this as an example](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html#two-way-computed-property), and trying to bind each checkbox to one property of the store:

```
Vue.use(Vuex);

var store = Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    lights: true,
    sound: false
  },
  mutations: {
    updateMessage(state, args) {
      state[args.name] = args.value;
    }
  }
});

Vue.component("my-switch", {
  props: ["name"],
  template: '<div>{{ name }} <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked"></div>',
  computed: {
    checked: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state[this.name];
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("updateMessage", { name: this.name, value: value });
      }
    }
  }
});

var v = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store: store
});
```

I have broken demo here:
https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/dVXeNL?editors=0010

The issue is that I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate the Vuex store via `new Vuex.Store({...})` (I would expect your code to throw an error, but apparently not.)

Also, you don't need the `Vue.use(Vuex)` line.

[Here's a working Codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBEKQq?editors=0010)